# PyTorch PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.torch'

Tags: permissions, pytorch

I'm running a PyTorch based ML program for image classification using Resnet50 model for transfer learning. I am getting below error regarding permission.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "imgc_pytorch.py", line 67, in 
>   model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 187, in resnet50
>   model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet50']))
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/model_zoo.py",
> line 59, in load_url
>   os.makedirs(model_dir)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
>   makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
>   mkdir(name, mode)
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.torch'

Looked up on this forum and it was suggested to add `'sudo'` before the file name, but getting error `"/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found"`

Comment: I am deploying this code on a GPU cluster provided by my company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change `model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet50'])` to `model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet50'], model_dir='~/.torch/')` like [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/model_zoo.html#torch.utils.model_zoo.load_url)

Comment: Since this is on the cluster, looks like the admin will have to do this right ?

Comment: @sigmoid I guess not. I mean you still have a user there right? So it should be fine for you to download the pertained model in your home directory

Comment: I have never worked on a container so I don't know much, but you can download the model(based on the model_urls) locally and then copy the files into your container and load them with model_zoo, right?

Comment: thanks i will try that...wish i cud upvote you, but dont have enough rep

Comment: no, still figuring out...BTW where should I change to model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet50'], model_dir='~/.torch/')

Comment: `TORCH_HOME=/mnt/test/torch export TORCH_HOME;cd /mnt/test;python imgc_pytorch.py`     did the trick. Works fine now